# Output: [<Signal_Param.Signals_Parameters object at 0x000000000A3BBA88>]

Tags: python

I'm developing a program that generate signals and after process them but I've a problem with some parameters.
I've created 2 classes: the first to define parameters and the second to get a value to the parameters.

If I want to print the parameters to check the correctness of data, I get this thing when I print:[<Signal_Param.Signals_Parameters object at 0x000000000A3BBA88>]

This is Parameters class:

```
 class Signals_Parameters:
    
    def __init__(self, name, minValue, maxValue):
        self.name = name
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue
```

This is the class to get the parameters value:

```
from Signal_Param import Signals_Parameters

class SignalDefinition:
   
    def signaldefinition(self):
        self.signal = []
        self.signal.append(Signals_Parameters("S1", 0, 100))
        print(self.signal)
SignalDefinition().signaldefinition()
```

How can I see the output as a str() with parameters?

Comment: Well, what output were you expecting?  Your class defines neither a `__str__()` nor a `__repr__()` method, so that default representation is all you get.

Comment: I need to use this data as str() in another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods in your `Signals_Parameters` class. If one of those methods is not defined, you see the reference of your object (`<Signal_Param.Signals_Parameters object at 0x000000000A3BBA88>`).

**`Signal_Param` content:**

```
class Signals_Parameters:

    def __init__(self, name, minValue, maxValue):
        self.name = name
        self.minValue = minValue
        self.maxValue = maxValue

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Name: {} ; Min: {} ; Max: {}".format(self.name, self.minValue, self.maxValue)
```

**`test1.py` content:**

```
from Signal_Param import Signals_Parameters


class SignalDefinition:

    def signaldefinition(self):
        self.signal = []
        self.signal.append(Signals_Parameters("S1", 0, 100))
        print(self.signal)


SignalDefinition().signaldefinition()
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test1.py
[Name: S1 ; Min: 0 ; Max: 100]
```

Comment: Is it also possible to get the output as dict?

Comment: Sure! It is possbile! Only you should use the following line: `self.signal.append(Signals_Parameters("S1", 0, 100).__dict__)`. The output will be: `[{'name': 'S1', 'minValue': 0, 'maxValue': 100}]
`